# How to save data into smart table in UI5?

Tags: odata, sapui5, batch-processing

I have a smart table which has editable fields, I want to save these multiple records in the backend. How should I achieve this?

```
oModel.create("/Set", [{obj1}, {obj2}])
oModel.createBatchOperation("/set", "POST" , obj1)
oModel.createKey("set" , obj)
oModel.submitChanges()
```

All of them
use batch call, giving
same error -- 400 -- XML parse error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel use below code

```
            var oModel = this.getView().getModel();//gets the v2 odata model
        oModel.setUseBatch(true);//setting batch true if not already set
        var jModel = oTable.getModel("jTabModel").getProperty("/Carriers");

        for (var i = 0; i < jModel.length; i++) {
            var oEntry = jModel[i];
            oModel.create("/FlightSet", oEntry, {
                method: "POST",
                success: function(data) {

                },
                error: function(e) {

                }
            });

        }
        oModel.submitChanges({
            success: function(data, response) {
                //To do
            },
            error: function(e) {
                //To do
            }
        });
```